# Error unable to Install Open CTI Demo Salesforce Lightning playground ORG

Tags: opencti

i was hoping i can get some help with "Open CTI Demo" package that i'm trying to install in a playgroup ORG and i'm getting the below error message. Also please see the attached screen shot.

[image]This app can't be installed.

There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.

(Task-Demo Call Task Layout) Cannot use field:WhatId in RelatedContent section.Task-Demo Call Task Layout: Cannot use field:WhatId in RelatedContent section.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this issue is coming. But I was able to install this package in one org. From there I have created another unmanaged packaged and removed the task layout. You can use this link to install the package, other steps are the same.

https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t0K000000wTvz

there are 2 known issues raised for this - have a look at the suggested workarounds:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eJZ7AAM
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001PYZAQA4&title=task-event-layouts-deploy-with-error-cannot-use-field-whatid-in-relatedcontent-section